# Android ExpandableListView with Swipe

Tags: android, list, listview, expandablelistview, swipe

I'm just curious.
Is it possible to combine an ExpandableListView with a Swipe-function in Android? To explain what I mean, imagine this scenario:
You touch an item in the list, a view is expanded. In this View you are able to swipe to left/right in order to view a new View without changing the background.

Comment if you don't understand, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You capture swipe via GestureDetector and change the view accordingly. The simplest approach would be probably a FrameLayout with several views in it, and make only one view visible at a time.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Would this approach be efficient is the expandable list contains around 100 elements and each element has 2-3 swipe-able views?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the version of Android you are using, but if you can use the AppCompat library v22, you can actually use a `CoordinatorLayout` and do an expansion of the view onTouch. Afterwards, in one of your child layouts, you can set the `SwipeDismissBehavior`on the expanded view (which should be a child of your `CoordinatorLayout`). This is one of the coolest new functionalities in Android. You should read more about it here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/tycallen/SwipeMenu-Expandable-ListView for `Swipable ExpandableListView`.